# What's the first shotacon anime?

Tags: anime-history

There are many anime portraying shota, but most of the female characters there do not have interest in the shota. What's the first shotacon anime where some female character is attracted to the shota?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's **Natsu e no Tobira (1981)**.

[image]

It's an erotic drama and not really part of the otaku culture that brought us classics such as Boku no Pico (2006). Speaking of which, that also happens to be the first shotacon anime that had a big impact, even though the romantic relationships were all among guys.

Also worth noting that Natsu e no Tobira is geared towards a female audience, while Boku no Pico is geared towards a male audience.

As far as otaku culture is concerned, though, it is very rare for female characters to be interested romantically in shotas. The topic is mostly played for gags, unless you are consuming pornographic content. And for that Boku no Pico was a trend starter.